# Postgres GIN on fixed length bit string

Tags: postgresql, similarity, gwt-gin

I'm try to create GIN for fast similarity search on bitsrings on postgres 9.6.

I use tanimoto/jaccard similarity metric:

`tanimoto = popcount(bs1 & bs2)/popcount(bs1 | bs2)`

where 0 - is totally not similar and 1 - is identical.

**update:**

popcount - is count of true bits. bs1, bs2 - bitstrings.

I use query like this:

`SELECT bs, tanimoto(B'11100000', bs) as t FROM test WHERE bs % B'11100000'`

on table:

```
 CREATE TABLE test (bs bit(8));
```

% operator is bool(tanimoto(bs, B'11100000') > treshold)

treshold configurable.

How can I enable GIN or how to implement operator_class if need?

I want to implement this http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ci200552r index

Comment: Please be more specific. Table definition, Postgres version, explain "tanimoto/jaccard" or add a link to details. Where do `bs1` and `bs2` come from? Same row or dynamically distinct rows?

Comment: Sorry to dig up old corpses. Tanimoto Distance is a measure of the similarity between 2 bitstrings. Much used in computational chemistry, where the (sometimes large) bitmask represents molecular fragments.
The Tanimoto distance is then used to find similar chemical compounds to a single given compound that you are searching for. So bs1 comes out of the table of compounds and bs2 is calculated from the given compund.